# IdentityServer3 as IDP for AWS Cognito

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect, federated-identity, amazon-cognito

just wondering if anyone has used AWS Cognito with IdentityServer3 as an OpenID Federated Identity for a user pool? I'm currently working on a Cognito project that may have to integrate with IdentityServer3 and was just wondering if anyone out there has gone through this successfully.

Comment: If you want a hosted server, Cognito User Pools recently launched a feature which allows you to host your own OAuth server along with the Signup/Signin pages.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-cognito-launches-public-beta-of-a-built-in-user-experience-for-sign-in-and-saml-federation-for-user-pools/

Comment: @RachitDhall Thanks for the reply, just so I'm understanding this feature correctly, what would the login flow look like on a high level for authenticating with an IdentityServer3 app from AWS Cognito? Would they log in via the hosted sign in page and then get redirected accordingly? And when they get redirected the app would get a token they could use to identify who the user is?